Unable to connect to MongoDB replicaset from scala mongodb driver
I am running mongodb replicaset in docker on localhost and I am able to connect to it from both command line and Mongodb Compass. When I try to connect from code I get Connection Refused. I am unable to figure out the reason. I upgraded scala mongo driver to latest version of 5.1.2 with no luck. Here's the code.
val settings: MongoClientSettings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
    .applyConnectionString(new ConnectionString("mongodb://user:password@ac-mongo-node10:50004,ac-mongo-node20:50005,ac-mongo-node30:50006/ac_app?authSource=admin&replicaSet=ac-dev"))
    .applyToConnectionPoolSettings(t => t.applySettings(ConnectionPoolSettings.builder().maxSize(10).build()))
    .build()

  val client = MongoClient(settings)

  val db = client.getDatabase("ac_app")
  val resourceCol: MongoCollection[Document] = db.getCollection("resources")

This is the exception
19:00:12.123 [main] INFO org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Adding discovered server ac-mongo-node10:50004 to client view of cluster
19:00:12.162 [main] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.connection - Connection pool created for ac-mongo-node10:50004 using options maxIdleTimeMS=0, minPoolSize=0, maxPoolSize=10, maxConnecting=2, waitQueueTimeoutMS=120000
19:00:12.169 [main] INFO org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Adding discovered server ac-mongo-node20:50005 to client view of cluster
19:00:12.173 [main] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.connection - Connection pool created for ac-mongo-node20:50005 using options maxIdleTimeMS=0, minPoolSize=0, maxPoolSize=10, maxConnecting=2, waitQueueTimeoutMS=120000
19:00:12.173 [main] INFO org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Adding discovered server ac-mongo-node30:50006 to client view of cluster
19:00:12.176 [main] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.connection - Connection pool created for ac-mongo-node30:50006 using options maxIdleTimeMS=0, minPoolSize=0, maxPoolSize=10, maxConnecting=2, waitQueueTimeoutMS=120000
19:00:12.177 [main] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Updating cluster description to  {type=REPLICA_SET, servers=[{address=ac-mongo-node30:50006, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}, {address=ac-mongo-node20:50005, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}, {address=ac-mongo-node10:50004, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}]
19:00:12.215 [cluster-ClusterId{value='669675e4c50e87196d639075', description='null'}-ac-mongo-node10:50004] INFO org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server ac-mongo-node10:50004
com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.AsynchronousSocketChannelStream$OpenCompletionHandler.failed(AsynchronousSocketChannelStream.java:124)
    at sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Invoker.java:128)
    at sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:278)
    at sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.finish(UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:198)
    at sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.onEvent(UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:213)
    at sun.nio.ch.KQueuePort$EventHandlerTask.run(KQueuePort.java:301)
    at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl$1.run(AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl.java:112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:252)
    ... 7 common frames omitted
19:00:12.219 [cluster-ClusterId{value='669675e4c50e87196d639075', description='null'}-ac-mongo-node10:50004] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Updating cluster description to  {type=REPLICA_SET, servers=[{address=ac-mongo-node30:50006, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}, {address=ac-mongo-node20:50005, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}, {address=ac-mongo-node10:50004, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused}}]


Do you run your scala app on the host system or in a docker? Do you use the same connection string in compass? How did you configure name resolution for "ac-mongo-nodeX0" domains for compass to resolve them to localhost?  Exception opening socket says it failed to complete SYN-ACK sequence on TCP level, so solution must be somewhere in virtual network configuration

I'm running scala app in host system (localhost) and connection string is same as that I use in MongoDB compass and from terminal. ac-mongo-nodeX0 is mapped in host file to 127.0.0.1. Ports of mongodb are exposed from docker to localhost.
